# How to access a dynamically created checkbox in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

In `form_load` event I create three check boxes. Then with a `button_click` event I want to check the state of the check boxes, but they are not available in my `if` statement. I found this piece of code as an example:

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.Top = 50;
chk.Left = 50;
chk.Text = "Check Box Test";
chk.Name = "chkTest";
this.Controls.Add(chk);
CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)Controls["chkTest"];
```

which works only if I check the state inside the `form_load`.  How do I access the check boxes with a button_click?

Comment: Show your actual code, not the sample you're trying to adapt

Comment: try with `CheckBox chkTest =this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Name =="chkTest");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to create a `List<CheckBox>` at the class level to hold a collection of the checkboxes you create.

Example:

```
List<CheckBox> CheckBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateCheckBoxes();
}

private void CreateCheckBoxes()
{
    //Create 3 checkboxes
    int intialTop = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.Top = intialTop;
        chk.Left = 50;
        chk.Text = "Check Box Test";
        chk.Name = "chkTest";
        this.Controls.Add(chk);
        CheckBoxes.Add(chk);

        intialTop += 20;
    }

    //You can access your checkboxes anywhere in Form1 now.
    var first = CheckBoxes.First();
    first.Text = "First Checkbox";
}
```

---

**Additional Example:**

This example shows adding two checkboxes to the form as well as giving them their own click event handlers.

```
CheckBox checkBoxA;
CheckBox checkBoxB;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add checkbox A
    checkBoxA = new CheckBox();
    checkBoxA.Top = 10;
    checkBoxA.Left = 50;
    checkBoxA.Text = "CheckBoxA";
    //Register the event handler for this checkbox
    checkBoxA.Click += new EventHandler(checkBoxA_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(checkBoxA);

    //Add checkbox B
    checkBoxB = new CheckBox();
    checkBoxB.Top = 30;
    checkBoxB.Left = 50;
    checkBoxB.Text = "checkBoxB";
    //Register the event handler for this checkbox
    checkBoxB.Click += new EventHandler(checkBoxB_Click);
    this.Controls.Add(checkBoxB);        
}

void checkBoxA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("CheckBoxA has been clicked!!!");
}

void checkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("CheckBoxB has been clicked!!!");
}
```

Comment: I stepped out of my application to check this directly. How would I rename the other CheckBoxes? continuing with the button_click event, how would I check the state of the checkboxes?  If I place the CheckBoxes on the form with the designer I use a simple 'if (Checkbox.Name [where this is the name of the Checkbox]) do something'

Comment: If you have a static number of checkboxes.  Declare those checkboxes in place of the `List<Checkbox>`.  If not, you can specify the checkbox by the index in the List.

Comment: ` private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateCheckBoxes();
        }

        private void CreateCheckBoxes()
        {
           
                CheckBox A = new CheckBox();
                A.Location = new Point(20, 20);
                A.Text = "Chk1";
                A.Name = "Chk1";
                this.Controls.Add(A);}`

Comment: Check out awudoin's answer.  It illustrates what I was saying as your other option pretty clearly.

Comment: [Comment above wasn't compete, hope this is easier to follow] I'm not following how to use this in a button_click event.  I use `CheckBox A = new Checkbox();` to create one of them.  Call the others B and C.  Change .Name and .Text property to "A","B","C" as well. Then within the method should I do `var one = A;`,`var two = B;`, `var three = C;`?  After doing this how do I check the state in a button_click event?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't refreshed. Now I understand about the class level Checkbox. I didn't realize it could be done that way.  I will apply this to my code.  Thank You.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of adding two checkboxes to the form and giving them event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier, you can create a class level CheckBox and then check that anywhere you need to in your code:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
private void Form1_Load()
{
   checkBox1.Name = "CheckBox1";
   checkBox1.Text = "Click Me!";
   checkBox1.Click += new EventHandler(checkBox1_Click);   // Only need this if you want a click handler
   this.Controls.Add(checkBox1);
}

private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You click the check box");
}

private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (checkBox1.Checked)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Check box is checked!");
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can iterate over the form's controls and search for the check boxes there:

```
private void CheckCheckBoxes(string checkBoxName)
{
   // this.Controls is a collection of all controls on the form (assuming this is run on the Form class)
   foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
   {
      if (control.Name == checkBoxName && control is CheckBox)
      {
         CheckBox checkBox = control as CheckBox;
         if (checkBox.Checked)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Check box is checked");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You may want consider adding the checkbox to the form in your example.

Comment: Thank you...can't believe I forgot that.